# Directly Adding Member to Group - OAuth 2.0 Confusion

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm attempting to allow all users to add themselves to my Google Group via js + html form. I'm using the group to send out newsletters. I currently don't have access to the admin user account for G Suite so I'm unable to see what options are available, but I'm getting confused with the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

If I make a request to insert member (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/insert) with the G Suite SDK Directory API, will a consent screen be presented to all users who fill out the form (with the goal of being added to the group).

I've read through this documentation but still am a bit confused:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

Comment: Hi ! I have tested the [insert member](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert) method of the API and this will basically add a member of the organization to the group without the use of a content screen. Note that you have shared the insert group methods instead of the insert member method in your question. Does this solve your question?

Comment: Whoops, yes I meant to share the insert member method. That answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [members insert method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert) of the G Suite Admin SDK will allow you to add members to an existing group and also attribute them a group role and mail delivery options.

This **will not require** the new members to pass through a consent screen to be added (note also that they must belong to the same organization).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: This is it, thanks! Just a quick note, depending on the permissions of my group I should be able to add members directly even if they are not part of the organization correct? I’ve been able to directly add member via the Groups UI with no issues.